# Simple ajax post not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am an AJAX noob. I was writing code to understand it, but no matter what I couldn't make it work. Textarea in the code should update `comment_area` of comment of `id=218` when user pressed "save" button. There is probably a mistake in my AJAX code which I couldn't find.

My AJAX script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").submit(function() {
        var text = $('#breaking_news_text').val();
        var id = 218,
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            data: {comment_area:text , id:id}
            success: function() {
                alert("sucess");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```
<div id="b_news">

        <form method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <div>
              <textarea id="breaking_news_text" class="breaking_news_text" rows="6" cols="50"  placeholder="Add text here..." required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>

            <input  type="button" id="save" value="Save Changes"/>

        </div>
        </form>

</div>
```

My update.php file

```
<?php 
include("./inc/connect.inc.php");

    if(isset($_POST['comment_area']))
    {
            $update = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['comment_area']);
            $sql = "update comments set comment_area='$update' Where id='".$_POST['id']."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

    }   
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). you're also not interrupting the form submission, so that's probably killing your ajax request as the page unloads.

Comment: You also need to add a preventDefault() to make sure the form doesnt go ahead and do its own submission

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: i didn't include anything , no error just nothing happens , not on web server and there is a comment_area  value in script .

Comment: You have a syntax error. The close curly brace of data needs a trailing comma.

Comment: If you're not on a webserver the HTTP request generated by the AJAX call will likely not work.

Comment: `var id = 218, `  replace the `,` with `;`

Comment: so i can't use axaj ? i use my computer wampserver .

Comment: can anyone say is my ajax code true or not ?

Answer (score 2):

The `submit` works on a `form` and you have it on the `input` element.

Try:

```
$("#b_news form").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); //this is required to stop the default form submission
```

Documentation can be [found here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Also, if these dom elements are dynamically loaded, you might want to [read up on `event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: "Did not work" is very vague for me to be able to help you. Please be more specific. Also, learn how to use breakpoints in the developer console. You can inspect the response and see what is going on

Comment: There isnot nay prblem in console .No errors . I tested my php file . It works perfect . Only problem in here this javascript code can't send variables to my .php file .

Comment: there is not any error in console . when i clicked the button . I changed javascript as you said .